# How to append the csv file in Github with Python code?

Tags: python, github

Below is the code:

```
with open("https://github.com/Metrics.csv", 'a+', newline='') as csvfile:
     thewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
     thewriter.writerow(['Columns1','Column2','Column3'])
```

Error:

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:"https://github.com/Metrics.csv"

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense. Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think you need to write a file locally, and then upload it to github some how. :) You can't "open" a file for writing with a URL link. :D

Comment: I have a csv file(Metrics.csv) in  my github repo with columns as below 
Team,issue_no,Title,Ideas/Features_Opened,Ideas/Features_Closed,Closed_date

I give API call to another Github repo where we create  issues to track  Automations/ features and issue open/closed  forevery month. So i get those details and  trying it to append to csv file to generate dashboard from that report.